# Understanding how a statement follows from another in a probability theory journal paper

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> I'm trying to understand how inequality $(5.3)$ follows from the inequality above it in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08564.pdf). The explanation given in the paper is that $(5.3)$ just follows from the previous inequality, so, I think the reason is trivial but I still don't understand.

I don't think a lot of background on what different random variables mean is necessary. Nevertheless, $G_n^\ast$ is a random graph, $X_t$ is an ergodic simple random walk on $G_n^\ast$ and $\pi$ is its stationary distribution. TV stands for total-variation (L-1) distance. Since $G_n^\ast$ is random, the distance $||P_x(X_{t+s}\in \cdot\vert G_n^\ast)-\pi||_{\rm{TV}}$ is random.

Inequality above $(5.3)$ is:
$$\mathbb{P}(G_n^\ast\in \mathcal{G}\vert \mathcal{F}_{i-1})\geq 1-\varepsilon$$

Inequality $(5.3)$ is:
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(||\mathbb{P}_x(X_{t+s}\in \cdot \vert G_n^\ast)-\pi ||_{\rm{TV}} = 1\{G_n^\ast\in \mathcal{G}\}||\mathbb{P}_x(X_{t+s}\in \cdot \vert G_n^\ast)-\pi ||_{\rm{TV}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right) \geq 1-\varepsilon $$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $d_x(t+s)$ denote the random TV term, you have
$$P(d_x(t+s) = \mathbf{1}\{G_n^* \in \mathcal{G}\} d_x(t+s) \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})
\ge P(1 = \mathbf{1}\{G_n^* \in \mathcal{G}\} \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) \ge 1-\epsilon,$$
because $1 = \mathbf{1}\{G_n^* \in \mathcal{G}\}$ implies $d_x(t+s) = \mathbf{1}\{G_n^* \in \mathcal{G}\} d_x(t+s)$. It is not equality because the latter equality could hold if $d_x(t+s)=0$ while $1 \ne \mathbf{1}\{G_n^* \in \mathcal{G}\}$.